# Can I customize the colors in my R terminal environment?

Tags: r

I'm running R version 2.13.1 and wondering if there is a way to get more interesting colors in the R terminal, either in bash or `tk-R`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) for writing/editing R scripts. In my opinion R Studio is the best GUI/IDE available for R development. In [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) under tools -> Options -> Appearance you can change the color of your R console and also change the fonts.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this by including information about how to customize colors in RStudio. (Otherwise, this does not really fully answer the question.)

Comment: I found RStudio not long after I posted this, and I definitely agree that it is great.

Answer (score 0):

In general you may have problem to have a syntax highlighter in terminal. If you already using R commander you may consider [RKWard](http://rkward.sourceforge.net/) as a GUI for your R programming. It is configurable and very effective. You can use is the same way as R in terminal or R commander. In Ubuntu you can install it through the software center.